# Functionally map a Spark SQL data type to a native Scala types

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am essentially looking for a way to get the mappings in [the Spark SQL data type table](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types) programmatically.

Yes, I can always write a match expression like so:

```
val tag = schemaType match {
  case ByteType => ClassTag[Byte]
  case ShortType => ClassTag[Short]
  ...
}
```

But the API has to expose some method that does the same (and probably the reverse as well) without all the typing. I just can't seem to find it.